# Assigning ID by multiple columns and time with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am looking to assign unique IDs to a pandas dataframe with these columns - date, name, product, elapsed_time. There should be an ID for any subsequent combination of date, name, and product. Elapsed_time is calculated column using timestamp with date HH:MM:SS. If within the same date, name, and product, the elapsed time is greater than 100 seconds, the ID should increment again for all following values until there is a change in date, name, or product. The dataframe is sorted by name then by timestamp.

```
| Date       | Name     |Product  | Elapsed_time | id
| --------   | -------- |-------- |--------      |--------      
| 10/25/23   | Bill     |A        |30            |1
| 10/25/23   | Bill     |A        |99            |1
| 10/25/23   | John     |B        |10            |2
| 10/25/23   | John     |B        |100           |3
| 10/25/23   | John     |B        |1             |3
| 10/25/23   | John     |B        |15            |3
| 10/26/23   | John     |C        |45            |4
| 10/27/23   | Carl     |A        |120           |5
| 10/27/23   | Carl     |A        |99            |5
| 10/27/23   | Carl     |A        |80            |5
| 10/27/23   | Carl     |A        |101           |6
| 10/27/23   | Carl     |B        |300           |7
| 10/27/23   | Carl     |A        |12            |8
| 10/27/23   | Carl     |A        |37            |8
```

Currently, I have the following line which increments for any combination of date, name, product, but I can't figure out how to add the elapsed time >= 100 logic.

```
df.insert(loc=0, column='id', value= df.set_index(['date','name','product']).index.factorize()[0]+1)
```

I've tried to create a T/F flag column for anywhere elapsed time >= 100, and then using a for loop, when it hits the flag, increment by 1. This works for that one row where elapsed time >=100, but it doesn't fill down to subsequent rows until date, name or product changes.

There's also the added complication that the dataset is not sorted by Product. In the last two rows, where product A reoccurs, this should have a separate id, even though elapsed_time is not greater than 100. This happens because the data is sorted by timestamp (not shown) so Carl could view Product A in the morning of 10/27 (id 5), then 101 seconds later, view Product A again (id 6), then view Product B later in the same day (id 7), then back to product A (id 8).

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: can you confirm that your rows are already sorted? If, not what should happen if you find again a product `B` in the last row?

Comment: @mozway the rows are sorted by name then by date, but products will reoccur throughout the column

Answer (score 0):

##### updated answer

Check if [`any`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) value changed among Date/Name/Product compared to the previous row (using [`shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html)), or if the value is greater or equal to 100, then increment with [`cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html):

```
cols = ['Date', 'Name', 'Product']
df['id'] = (df[cols].ne(df[cols].shift())
     .assign(x=df['Elapsed_time'].ge(100))
     .any(axis=1).cumsum()
    )
```

Output:

```
        Date  Name Product  Elapsed_time  id
0   10/25/23  Bill       A            30   1
1   10/25/23  Bill       A            99   1
2   10/25/23  John       B            10   2
3   10/25/23  John       B           100   3
4   10/25/23  John       B             1   3
5   10/25/23  John       B            15   3
6   10/26/23  John       C            45   4
7   10/27/23  Carl       A           120   5
8   10/27/23  Carl       A            99   5
9   10/27/23  Carl       A            80   5
10  10/27/23  Carl       A           101   6
11  10/27/23  Carl       B           300   7
12  10/27/23  Carl       A            12   8
13  10/27/23  Carl       A            37   8
```

##### original answer

If your rows are already sorted by date/name/product, you can just compute the group and add `df['Elapsed_time'].ge(100).cumsum()`:

```
df['id'] = (df.groupby(['Date', 'Name', 'Product']).ngroup()
              .add(1+df['Elapsed_time'].ge(100).cumsum())
           )
```

Output:

```
       Date  Name Product  Elapsed_time  id
0  10/25/23  Bill       A            30   1
1  10/25/23  Bill       A            99   1
2  10/25/23  John       B            10   2
3  10/25/23  John       B           100   3
4  10/25/23  John       B             1   3
5  10/25/23  John       B            15   3
6  10/26/23  John       C            45   4
```

Comment: this mostly works - I should have clarified that when there's a row with the elapsed time >= 100, it should only increment ID if date, name, and product are all still the same. So, if there was a row 7 with 10/27/23 Carl A 120, id should be 5

Comment: @user22977701 that was the essence of my comment to your question, then one need to use a `groupby.cumsum`, can you update the example to show something more complex and I'll update the answer ;)

Comment: updated - the data set is not sorted by product, but it is sorted by a timestamp, so there could be a case where Carl views product A (id 1) then product C (id 2) then product d (id 3) then product A again (id 4) on the same day. The group of date/name/product could reoccur but should have different ID.

Comment: @user22977701 got it, see update

Comment: amazing!! this works great - thank you !

Comment: Try to use .values for direct comparison. Better for large datasets.
df['id'] = (df[cols].ne(df[cols].shift().values)  
               .assign(x=df['Elapsed_time'].ge(100))
               .any(axis=1).cumsum())